# Reliable way to get a machine wake + user logged in notification in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've tried registering for `NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification` with `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`, but it never fires when my MacBook Pro wakes from sleep. Other notifications that I register for fire, so it's not an issue with how I'm registering for it.

Basically I need to get notified when a user's machine has woken from sleep, *and* the user has logged back in, or the machine has woken and the user is back in their account, in the case that the login screen wasn't displayed to them. If I have to handle that with multiple notifications, that's fine as well.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!
Cody

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The notification `NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification` does not come from the default notification center. This works:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
                     selector:@selector(wakeFromSleep:)
                         name:NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification
                       object:nil];
```

There exists the [Apple Q&A 1340](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html) regarding this question.

This covers only the waking aspect of your question. You don't get a notification when you log in originally, because you app is not running then. But you probably mean the password prompt for unlocking after sleep, and there you are fine.