# NSApplication delegate: Determining the return from hibernate mode: - didWakeUp?

Tags: cocoa, hibernate, delegates, nsapplication, wakeup

I'm currently wondering if it is possible, just like on iOS the somehow have a delegate called once OSX returns from hibernate mode, e.g. on opening the MacBook from sleeping?

I had a look at the `NSApplication delegates` here: [Apple NSApplicationDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW2) but couldn't find anything helpful.

On iOS the closest thing that comes to it is may the `- applicationWillEnterForeground:` that is documented in the [Apple UIApplicationDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE**

[Reliable way to get a machine wake + user logged in notification in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402179/reliable-way-to-get-a-machine-wake-user-logged-in-notification-in-cocoa) exactly solves this question!

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
                 selector:@selector(wakeFromSleep:)
                     name:NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification
                   object:nil];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reliable way to get a machine wake + user logged in notification in Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402179/reliable-way-to-get-a-machine-wake-user-logged-in-notification-in-cocoa)

Comment: Absolutely! Great, thank you Rob.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reliable way to get a machine wake + user logged in notification in Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402179/reliable-way-to-get-a-machine-wake-user-logged-in-notification-in-cocoa)